# TimeSeries Rest API https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/../timeseries returning empty

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api

I am trying to fetch performance data using Google monitoring REST API (code Sample ). But it is returning empty data "{}". Also observed that it is retuning ContentEncoding of response is "gzip" type.

```
private static void executeMetricUrl(Credential credential) throws Exception {
// Set up and execute a Google Cloud Storage request.
long startMillis = System.currentTimeMillis() - ((60 * 20) * 1000);
Date currentDate = new Date(startMillis);
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

//formatted value of current Date
System.out.println("Milliseconds to Date: " + df.format(currentDate));

//System.out.println(currentDate);
String URI = "https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/" + projectId+"/timeSeries/?";
String interval =
    "interval.end_time=" + df.format(System.currentTimeMillis()) + "&interval.start_time="
        + df.format(currentDate);
String filter =
    "filter=metric.type=\"compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization\""; //AND metric.labels.instance_name=sampleinstance-1";
String aggregation =
    "aggregation.perSeriesAligner=ALIGN_RATE&aggregation.alignmentPeriod=60s&aggregation.crossSeriesReducer=ALIGN_MEAN";

String finalUrl = URI+filter+"&"+interval;
System.out.println("Final URL ::: "+finalUrl);
TimeInterval interval1 = TimeInterval
    .newBuilder()
    .setStartTime(Timestamps.fromMillis(startMillis))
    .setEndTime(
            Timestamps.fromMillis(System
                    .currentTimeMillis())).build();

HttpRequestFactory requestFactory = httpTransport.createRequestFactory(credential);
GenericUrl url = new GenericUrl(finalUrl);
HttpRequest request = requestFactory.buildGetRequest(url);
//HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();    
//request.setHeaders(headers.setAcceptEncoding("gzip"));
HttpResponse response = request.execute();
String html = "";
BufferedReader  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getContent()));  
String inputLine;
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
  html += inputLine + "\n";
}
 System.out.println("content ::: "+html);
```

}

I am getting proper time-series data with the same filter and interval using MetricServiceClient. Am I missing something in RESt API approach.

Comment: Can you try to test first using [Method: projects.timeSeries.list API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list) and see if you get the same empty results. Please consider that  only time series that contain data points in the specified interval are included in the response.

Comment: yes, I have tried on this page as well, getting the same empty {} result. I am trying to get 20 mins back data from the current time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to reproduce your case using the [Method: projects.timeSeries.list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list)

I used the following parameters

```
name : project/your-project

filter : metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization" AND  metric.labels.instance_name = "instance-name"

interval.startTime : 2020-01-10T15:01:23.045123456Z

interval.endTime : 2020-01-11T15:01:23.045123456Z
```

I got the following response:

```
  "timeSeries": [
    {
      "metric": {
        "labels": {
          "instance_name": "instance-name"
        },
        "type": "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/utilization"
      },
      "resource": {
        "type": "gce_instance",
        "labels": {
          "instance_id": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
          "zone": "XXXXXXXXX",
          "project_id": "your-project"
        }
      },
      "metricKind": "GAUGE",
      "valueType": "DOUBLE",
      "points": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-01-11T15:01:00Z",
            "endTime": "2020-01-11T15:01:00Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 0.00097723160608135617
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-01-11T15:00:00Z",
            "endTime": "2020-01-11T15:00:00Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 0.00092651031620789577
          }
....................................................
```

I would suggest to pay attention on how do you set the startTime and EndTime.

It should be a timestamp in RFC3339 UTC "Zulu" format [TimeInterval](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/TimeInterval)

Also try to include the instance name in your filter.

Comment: Thanks Marian. I have tried with your TimeInterval , returning data now. It seems to be some problem in the time interval.

Comment: If my answer was useful, please mark my answer as accepted for greater visibility for community